# Adding parameters to Q_Object constructor

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qobject

When I create a new `Q_OBJECT` class in Qt Creator, it makes this default constructor. I want to add another parameter so that I can pass user input but I'm not sure how to do this since `QObject` is the first parameter and have no idea how to skip the first parameter and pass the user input on the `QString userInput` parameter.

**How to take this default:**

```
public:
            explicit renderJob(QObject *parent = 0);
```

**To do this**

```
public:
    explicit renderJob(QObject *parent = 0,QString userInput);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `C++` if you put default parameters these should be in the last positions. In addition, the QObject parameter should be passed to the base class constructor. For example:

```
class renderJob: public {BaseObjectClass}
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit renderJob(QString userInput, QObject *parent = 0);
}

[...]

renderJob::renderJob(QString userInput, QObject *parent):
{BaseObjectClass}(parent)
{
    [...]
}
```